# Unix time stamp gives different results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp-with-timezone

I am using the following code to generate time stamps I always get different results for the same input on

```
        $EventDateZone = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '-', $record['Date']), new DateTimeZone(Config::get('app.timezone')));
        $EventDate = strtotime($EventDateZone->format("Y-m-d"));
        $EventTimeZone = new DateTime($record['Time'], new DateTimeZone(Config::get('app.timezone')));
        $EventTime = strtotime($EventTimeZone->format("H:i:s"));
```

The variables `$record['Date]` includes `01/04/2014` and `$record['Time']` includes `09:26:00 AM` and `Config::get('app.timezone')` is `Asia/Dubai`

The problem with the converted time it is always different here are the result for the converted time `1398576360` and `1398662760`

I need the generated time stamp to be identical as this record will be stored in the database and I don't want to have it duplicated.

Comment: Why are you separating time and date? You can use DATETIME columns in MySQL.

Comment: I get them in a CSV format and I have to store them in the database this way regulations issue,  I can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date value does not contain a time, and the time value does not contain a date. UNIX timestamps however are compound values which are date-time values and must contain both. When you instantiate a new `DateTime` object and you give it an *incomplete* timestamp (i.e. missing either date or time), it fills in the missing values from the current time. And that will of course always be different.

You'll have to instantiate the `DateTime` object with both to get your UNIX timestamp. You cannot output a UNIX timestamp separately for date and time, because that doesn't make any sense. Your `strtotime` code doesn't make any sense. You can separate the `DateTime` object into date and time components again later if necessary, but not into two separate UNIX timestamps.

```
$event = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'd/m/Y H:i:s',
    "$record[Date] $record[Time]",
    new DateTimeZone(Config::get('app.timezone'))
);
echo $event->getTimestamp();
echo $event->format('Y-m-d');
echo $event->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your suggestion and of course the time stamp was wrong therefore I changed now it works as it suppose to work